# Does $x\neq y\Rightarrow |x|\neq |y|$?

Tags: calculus

Prove or disprove if $x\neq y\Rightarrow |x|\neq |y|$, $x,y$ are real numbers.

$x-y\neq 0$, then $|x-y|\neq 0$. What should I do next?

Comment: What kind of thing are $x$ and $y$? - If they are positive (or non-negative) integers, you get one answer, If they are integers or real numbers you get a simple counter-example. In the complex numbers, numbers with the same modulus live on a circle.

Comment: $x,y$ are real numbers.

Comment: Small remark: What you want to prove / or disprove is [injectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) of the function $f(x)=|x|$. If you want to disprove something, just find an example where the argument is not true.

Comment: @P.Siehr sorry i don't know injectivity.

Comment: oh! is this 1-1 mapping you are talking about?

Comment: 1-1 mapping is a [bijection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection). That is, if a mapping is injective and surjective.  But if you don't know these terms yet, ignore that part of my comment.  Still, the part "If you want to disprove something, just find an example where the argument is not true." is important for you.

Comment: thanks ... I understood.

Comment: Consider the reverse assertion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the statement is wrong showing counterexample is enough. Note that $x\neq 0$, then $x\neq -x$, but $|x|=|-x|$.

Answer (score 5):

This is not true.
$$-2\neq2\text{ but }  |-2|=|2|=2$$

Answer (score 4):

No. For example, $1\neq -1$, however $|1|=|-1|$.

The other way around, however, is valid. If $|x|\neq |y|$, then $x\neq y$ (this is easy to prove, since it is simply the cotrapositive of $x=y\implies |x|=|y|$).

Answer (score 2):

No. $x\neq -x \nRightarrow |x| \neq |-x|$

Answer (score 1):

Note that the statement is the same as this one (its contrapositive):
$$|x|=|y|\implies x=y$$
This is true iff $xy\geq 0.$